# How many maritime launch platforms were ever built?

Tags: launchpad, record, sea-launch

How many maritime launch platforms has ever been built and used for orbital space launches?

Comment: Do you count US navy vessels with vertical launch anti-satellite capability?

Comment: Yes those are ok too

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_41_Vertical_Launching_System list a lot of ships...

Comment: Those ships can launch rockets into space?

Comment: That launch system can house the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIM-161_Standard_Missile_3, yes.

Comment: @JoeJobs in that case you might consider asking only about orbital launches, or simply exclude military or weapons-only launch systems. It's just a thought, but it may encourage timely answers.

Comment: @JonCuster For the record, the US Navy at least states it does not have standing anti-satellite capability. They do have missiles that can reach space, but those are only for the purpose of shooting down incoming missiles, not satellites. They did convert one of these for Operation Burn Frost which did shoot down a satellite, but all such changes have been reverted, it is not a standing capability. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Burnt_Frost

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto - understood, but since a standard VLS system can host such a missile, all vessels with that VLS system could be a launch platform.

Comment: Fair enough. And in any case, any ship with SM-3 missiles can reach space for their primary mission, but are clearly suborbital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dedicated orbital rocket launch platforms, there has only been a handful, [Sea Launch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Launch) being the most notable one, along with a [Chinese one](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/science/news/china-launch-nine-satellites-long-march-11-rocket-first-sea-based-commercial-take-off-2296233), and [Italian Broglio System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broglio_Space_Center). Of these, only Sea Launch was truly mobile, the others were fixed platforms on the sea rather than ships.

Virtually every submarine that carries nuclear weapons can at least launch something sub-orbital, many have actually launched orbital satellites as well, as a means to get rid of a surplus of weapons post-cold war. In addition is any Aegis BMD system, of which there are many, which can launch weapons in to space to destroy incoming ballistic missiles. Getting an accurate count of all of these past systems would be difficult, but per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_missile_submarine) there is around 30 active ballistic missile submarines and [36 Aegis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aegis_Ballistic_Missile_Defense_System) equipped BMD ships, 33 US and 3 Japanese. Previously active systems are numbered even higher, but I'm probably not going to be able to get an accurate count of such systems.

Of these systems, I have found some evidence that [Russia](http://www.spacetoday.org/Rockets/Plowshares/Submarine.html) has launched satellites using some of these submarines, but the number of these launches I am having a difficult time getting a reasonable count. I can't find any evidence that the US has done so.

Comment: There was also the Italian San Marco platform. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broglio_Space_Center Feel free to add it to your list.

Comment: Hadn't even heard of that one, thanks for the information, and added!

Comment: Might worth asding this link - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine-launched_satellite

Comment: Only the Sea Launch was mobile? The Chinese one seems to be docked. No idea about the Italian one

Comment: You are correct, only Sea Launch was actually mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Undoubtedly not a complete list, but the "easy pickings" include  [Sea Launch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Launch)

> By 2014, it had assembled and launched thirty-two rockets, with an
> additional three failures and one partial failure. All commercial
> payloads have been communications satellites intended for
> geostationary transfer orbit with such customers as EchoStar, DirecTV,
> XM Satellite Radio, PanAmSat, and Thuraya.
>
> The launcher and its payload are assembled on a purpose-built ship Sea
> Launch Commander in Long Beach, California, US. The assembled
> spacecraft is then positioned on top of the self-propelled platform
> Ocean Odyssey and moved to the equatorial Pacific Ocean for launch,
> with the Sea Launch Commander serving as command center. The sea-based
> launch system means the rockets can be fired from the optimal position
> on Earth's surface, considerably increasing payload capacity and
> reducing launch costs compared to land-based systems

and a [Chinese](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/jun/05/china-launches-rocket-from-yellow-sea-platform-for-first-time) platform.

It appears the Sea Launch platform is now owned by a Russian conglomerate, perhaps more for 'show and pride' than for actual functionality.

Thanks to "OM" for mentioning  an [Italian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broglio_Space_Center) platform.

> Developed in the 1960s through a partnership between the Sapienza
> University of Rome's Aerospace Research Centre and NASA, the BSC
> served as a spaceport for the launch of both Italian and international
> satellites (1967–1988). The center comprises a main offshore launch
> site, known as the San Marco platform, as well as two secondary
> control platforms and a communications ground station on the mainland.
>
> In 2003 a legislative decree handed the Italian Space Agency
> management of the center, beginning in 2004, and the name changed from
> the previous San Marco Equatorial Range.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broglio_Space_Center) While the ground
> station is still in use for satellite communications, the BSC is not
> currently used as a launch site